# .htaccess rewrite rule to make longer url work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule that allows me to be able to have a url like this..

```
http://example.com/randyt
```

and convert it to

```
http://example.com/?aff=randyt
```

It's working however, I also have other links that need to be used such as....

```
example.com/members/aff/go/randyt

example.com/members

example.com/members/signup
```

and so on. The rewrite rule I have ignores those urls and just goes to
    example.com

Please help me add something to this so it will not ignore any url with the /members or /members/....  in it.

Here is the code I am using now...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) ?aff=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Sorry about the comments section I am new here lol.

So here is the above code with the added code that someone suggested

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) ?aff=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members 
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

When I try to use the extended url it still goes back to the base url showing only index.php from the root directory.

When someone uses a url like this....

```
example.com/members/aff/go/randyt
```

I need it to stay in the members directory using that affiliate code. The current program should take care of that.

Here is the .htaccess code in the members directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
#    RewriteBase /members
    RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
#  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>
```

That code was pre-written by the company I purchased the program from.

So to sum this up, I need 2 different things to happen...

If someone uses:

```
example.com/randyt     (randyt can be any username)
```

it needs to stay on example.com showing that page (index.php file)

If someone uses:

```
example.com/members/aff/go/randyt    (again randyt can be any username)
```

it needs to stay in the members directory and use the purchased script.

Comment: Is `/members/` a real directory and does it also have a .htaccess?

Comment: yes it is a real directory and it also has it's own .htaccess file that it needs

Comment: ok then `/members/.htaccess` will override this root .htaccess. Show content from `/members/.htaccess` and clarify what's not working.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

#    RewriteBase /members
    RewriteRule ^public public.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^js.php js.php [L]
    RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|csv|html)$ index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
#  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
</IfModule>

Comment: Code doesn't belong to comments, edit your question and post it there. **And clarify what exactly is not working for you**

Comment: How is your folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in `/members/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /members/

RewriteRule ^public/?$ public.php [L,NC]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members 
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

This condition will check if the Requested URI contains a string starting with /member  then it will be passed unchanged to its destination.

Comment: that does not seem to work. I have tried adding it above the other code and below the other code and neither work.